# Expanding Fourier Series of $f(x)=x^2$ where $0<x<1$ (even and odd)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I tried to solve Fourier series (which appeared on title) and ended up to below solution :

on even state :

$
\phi(x)= \begin{cases} 
x^2 & 0<x<1 \\
x^2 & -1<x<0 
\end{cases}
$

$a_{0}=\dfrac{2}{3}$ and also $a_{n}=\dfrac{4(-1)^n}{n^2\pi^2}$

on odd state I reached below answer :

$
\phi(x)= \begin{cases} 
x^2 & 0<x<1 \\
-x^2 & -1<x<0
\end{cases}
$

$a_{0}=0$ and $b_{n}=\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{-2}{n\pi}& n \text{ is even} \\
\dfrac{-2}{n\pi}-\dfrac{8}{n^3\pi^3}& n \text{ is odd} 
\end{cases}$

I would appreciate any help to confirm I this answer is true or not.

Comment: $b_{n}=\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{-2}{n\pi}& n \text{ is even} \\
\dfrac{+2}{n\pi}-\dfrac{8}{n^3\pi^3}& n \text{ is odd} 
\end{cases}$ Not 

$\color{red}{\dfrac{-2}{n\pi}-\dfrac{8}{n^3\pi^3}}$

Comment: tanx (واقعا زحمت شد!)

Comment: you're always welcome